Managing react-oauth google login and connecting it to backend golang with gin and goth
I'm trying to implement google login in my react frontend using react-oauth and go as backend with gin and goth
this it the rendered GoogleLogin in the frontend
<GoogleLogin
            onSuccess={handleGoogleLoginSuccess}
            onError={handleGoogleLoginFailure}
            useOneTap
            theme="outline"
            text="signin_with"
            shape="circle"
            
            
          />

with this onSuccess
const handleGoogleLoginSuccess = async(response: CredentialResponse) => { 
  try {
    console.log("Google login success: ", response)
    const data = await axios.post(`${API_URL}/auth/google/callback`, {token: response.credential})
    const {token, user} = data.data

    Cookies.set("token", token, {expires: 1})
    Cookies.set("username", user, {expires: 1})
    
  } catch (error) {
    console.error("Google login failed: ", error)
  }   
}

in my backend the route for auth/google/callback is this
func CallbackGoogleHandler(c *gin.Context, usecase *usecase.UserUsecase) {
q := c.Request.URL.Query()
q.Add("provider", "google")
c.Request.URL.RawQuery = q.Encode()
user, err := gothic.CompleteUserAuth(c.Writer, c.Request)
if err != nil {
    c.JSON(http.StatusBadRequest, gin.H{"error": err.Error()})
    return
}
token, username, err := usecase.HandleGoogleCallback(c.Request.Context(), user)
if err != nil {
    c.JSON(http.StatusInternalServerError, gin.H{"error": err.Error()})
    return
}
c.JSON(200, gin.H{
    "token": token,
    "user":  username,
})

}
the problem :
when i login using the GoogleLogin, it will log google login success with the credential like so
{
credential : (i think the jwt),
client_id : google client id??,
select_by : "btn"
}

but after that since i post the response.credential to the backend
it gets a 400 bad request error with the error : "no provider for google exists"
what i meant was to decode the jwt in the server backend, get the user data in the backend and send the token and username back to the frontend
